# Answer deleted for no real reason

Tags: discussion

Given that [fdisk -l shows 16 ram disks /dev/ram0 ... /ram15](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703576/ubuntu-15-10-fdisk-l-shows-16-ram-disks-dev-ram0-ram15) asks "If not, how can I get rid of that fdisk output?" Perhaps you could explain why the one answer that actually deals with the OP's question gets deleted AND includes 2 other possible options, while the answer that remains makes no attempt to do so?

Comment: How does it deal with the OP's question?

Answer (score 3):

You're right, upon re-reading the question and the answer it is an attempt to answer the question. I have undeleted it.

Answer (score 0):

You've got a point there: I too think the answer shouldn't have been deleted, as it kinda answers the question (meaning: the first method is theoretically a perfect method to accomplish [what OP is clearly after](https://askubuntu.com/questions/703576/ubuntu-15-10-fdisk-l-shows-16-ram-disks-dev-ram0-ram15#comment1035498_703584), although it's badly implemented).

That being said, your answer should have been downvoted / edited: it misses all the devices not handled by the `sd_mod` module.

All in all since that is improveable through an edit, I think it should be undeleted.

---

I'm putting this separately since it strays from the answer to the question.

Since only stating negatives always seems critical, to tell the full story: moderators are right 99% of the times: that answer was really borderline, since it was correct in its gist but wrong in its implementation.

Comment: -1 it doesn't even answer the question "technically".

Comment: @muru "Is it safe to delete them? If not, how can I get rid of that fdisk output?": it seems to be answering the question to me, although not in a good way. What am I missing?

Comment: Really guys? 43 comments? I am disappoint. Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33493/discussion-on-answer-by-kos-answer-deleted-for-no-real-reason).

Comment: @Seth Aw, I was just getting started. Ok, chat it is.